# 'New' instead of virtual + overide hack for high-performance and inlining

Tags: c#, performance, function, overriding

Virtual functions in C# (.NET), under-the-hood incurs an overhead of an extra method table reference, and also will never be inlined.

So, I'm wondering if in a high-performance scenario, though, its not the recommended way, is better to hide the older method with new, for better performance, and achieving JIT inlining as well.

Is this an OKAY practice?

Are there any consequences other than when retyping to a base class (which incidentally, can be 'partially' harmless in the scenario where it derives directly from an interface.

**Summary:**

Let me quickly summarize the comments and answers so far, below, for the benefit of others.

1. Its almost never a good idea, compromising polymorphism and readability.
2. Inlining does provide a signification difference in certain cases, from my tests.
3. *Research required:* There's a possibility the JIT compiler might inline these virtual methods. (Possibly only under sealed classes).

Any reference to documentation, or 'inside scoop' on the behavior of the JIT compiler in this aspect would be really helpful :)

Comment: Performance aside, what will the impact be to readability?  Premature optimizations that sacrifice readability and intent are the death of a good codebase.  Perhaps this is one such instance.

Comment: Also, even in high-performance scenarios, I highly doubt this would be noticeable. Have you profiled your application to find any perf bottlenecks?

Comment: If you are worried about this level of perf.... Net is the wrong  platform for you.

Comment: I do not disagree at all. I'm considering its usage only in closed internal scenarios where numerous repeated calls are incurred on the derived class modules, each of which override the methods.

Comment: @pvl I don't mean to insist on the issue, but please bear in mind that even in-house systems will probably be maintained by people other than yourself. Readability is still important.

Comment: If you're having performance problems, it seems incredibly unlikely that overriding is your bottleneck. Have you profiled your code? Have you tried your idea and then compared its performance?

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Calls through interfaces use virtual dispatch anyway.

Comment: @dcastro - Yes, it gives me quite a bit of kick actually. Punched up from approx 44sec to 27secs for one piece of code, with compiler optimizations, with proper warms-up for JIT to do its thing. I think I'd mostly attribute it to the inlining.

Comment: @BenVoigt - True. That just adds another layer, making it double the cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having virtual methods is a feature.  It provides additional functionality.  That functionality is not free (although it is cheap).  If you don't need that functionality, you can turn it off, and possibly gain some marginal performance benefits; these may or may not be enough to matter (you would need to do some performance testing to know; and of course, be warned that benchmarking microoptimizations is hard to do correctly, so be careful).

If you need the feature, and want to have polymorphic behavior, then turning it off really isn't an option.  [You could attempt to write your own system of virtual methods without using the language's feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one.aspx?Redirected=true), but your implementation is almost certainly going to be slower, so I would advise against it.

So in short, if you need the functionality, turn it on, if you don't, leave it off.  The decision is almost certainly not going to be made based on performance considerations, but rather the requirements of the code you are writing.

Comment: I agree. I was just wondering if there are any consequences, that I may have missed. And thanks for the reference to Eric Lippert's article.

Comment: Sure there are consequences.  Your methods won't be virtual.  If you're ever expecting to use polymorphism, you won't be able to, or you'll be paying the (again, very marginal) costs whenever you want to be able to.  If you really don't need it, then you don't need it.  There's a reason methods aren't virtual by default; they usually don't need to be.

Comment: Yes. I wonder if there's any particular reason why virtual methods can't get inlined by the JIT. In many cases, it shouldn't be difficult to deduce the real method during JIT compilation. The virtual dispatch cost can be considering marginal in 'almost' all scenarios. But inlining has quite a significant effect (for high-perf scenarios) in many cases.

Comment: @pvl If the compiler can prove that a given implementation of the method *will* be called, then it may well do that.  Note that the method or the class would likely need to be sealed for it to be able to make such a determination, else it couldn't be sure that the type hasn't been overridden by a sub-class with a different implementation.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just rephrasing you, but to confirm, does that mean it would still inline virtual methods (possibly only inside sealed classes) under certain scenarios?

Comment: @pvl I would expect it to.  You would need to do some research/experimentation to find out if it actually does do so in all of the cases in which it would be allowed to do so.